# What is the difference between operating temperature and junction temperature of an IC?

Tags: integrated-circuit, temperature, vlsi, maximum-ratings

On Wikipedia, I found that these are the same. However, in datasheets I find two different temperature ranges.

Can somone explain the difference to me please?

Comment: Context is needed. Only you know what you saw in an undisclosed data sheet and so there can be no explanation.

Comment: Same difference between air temperature and body temperature

Answer (score 4):

Operating temperature generally refers to the temperature of the environment.

Junction temperature refers to the temperature of the junctions within a integrated circuit or component.